# Impressora de etiqueta Argox: A_Prn_Text - Variable Is Error

Tags: delphi

Segue a função:

```
function  A_Prn_Text     ( x,y,ori,font,typee,hor_factor,ver_factor:integer;mode:char;numeric:integer;data:String):integer;stdcall;external 'WINPPLA.DLL';
```

Segue o código:

```
while not DMRetaguarda.QConItem.eof do
begin
  for i := 1 to strtoint(edit5.text) do
    begin
      A_Prn_Text(200, 360, 0, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideChar(AnsiString(copy(dmretaguarda.qconitemdescricao.asstring, 1, 29))));
      if length(dmretaguarda.qconitemdescricao.asstring) > 29 then
        A_Prn_Text(180, 360, 0, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideChar(AnsiString(copy(dmretaguarda.qconitemdescricao.asstring, 30, 29))));
      A_Prn_Text(175, 360, 0, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideChar(AnsiString('____________________________________')));
      A_Prn_Text(150, 360, 0, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideChar(AnsiString('MARCA: '+copy(dmretaguarda.qconitemmarca.asstring, 1, 30))));
      A_Prn_Text(130, 360, 0, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideChar(AnsiString('MODELO: '+copy(dmretaguarda.qconitemmodelo.asstring, 1, 30))));
      A_Prn_Text(110, 360, 0, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideChar(AnsiString('REF.: '+copy(dmretaguarda.qconitemreferencia.asstring, 1, 35))));
      loc12 := dmretaguarda.qconitemlocal1.asstring;
      if dmretaguarda.qconitemlocal2.asstring <> '' then
        loc12 := loc12 + ' e '+dmretaguarda.qconitemlocal2.asstring;
      A_Prn_Text(85, 360, 0, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideCHar(AnsiString('LOCAL: '+loc12)));
      A_Prn_Text(20, 180, 0, 9, 6, 0, 1, 'n', 2, PWideCHar(AnsiString('COD.: '+copy(dmretaguarda.qconitemcodigo.asstring, 7, 7))));
      A_Prn_Barcode(10, 360, 0, 'E', 0, 0, 60, 'A', 1, PWideCHar(AnsiString(dmretaguarda.qconitemcodigo.asstring)));
      A_Print_Out(1, 1, 1, 1);
    end;
  DMRetaguarda.QConItem.next;
end;
```

Esse codigo deveria imprimir de acordo com as minhas coordenadas, que a partir da query que está rodando vai atribuir os valores que digitei no meu formulário, porém ele está dando esse erro logo na primeira linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dizer o que pode ser isso?

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Alguma ideia amigo?

Comment: @Caputo, Alguma ideia?

Comment: Se o parametro é string, porque você está convertendo para ansistring e depois para PWideChar? O que acontece se passar a string diretamente?

Comment: Ja sim amigo, e nada :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while not DMRetaguarda.QConItem.eof do
begin
  for i := 1 to strtoint(edit5.text) do
    begin
      A_Prn_Text(200, 360, 1, 9, 5, 1, 1, 'n', 2, PWideChar(AnsiString(copy(dmretaguarda.qconitemdescricao.asstring, 1, 29))));
      end;
end;
```

Segundo minha função acima que pesquisei bastante, o problema é que só é permitido 1,2,3 e 4.

Eu apenas mudei a numeração do `ori`, da função:

```
function  A_Prn_Text     ( x,y,ori,font,typee,hor_factor,ver_factor:integer;mode:char;numeric:integer;data:String):integer;stdcall;external 'WINPPLA.DLL';
```

e funcionou :D